# Accepting Nominations — Who should moderate this site? / Приймаємо номінації на роль модератора цього сайту

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderation

Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until the community is large enough to hold a proper election, we will be appointing three provisional Moderators to fill those roles.

We need your help. Please nominate folks you would like to see become provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide valuable insight to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).**

### The Nomination Process:

- **Nominate a user** by posting an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Use the template at the bottom of this post to complete your nomination.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self-nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- **Tell us about the candidates.** Nominations can include links to other activities like Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **Nominees!** Please indicate your acceptance by editing the answer to accept/decline the nomination. And please ensure your profile email is correct so we can contact you. Optionally, you are encouraged to write a bit about yourself following your acceptance.

  > I accept/decline this nomination.
  >
  > Hi, I am name/location/fun fact (all optional). I live in <location>, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are…

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active during the earliest weeks of this site's creation
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

---

### Nomination Template

To nominate a candidate, copy and paste the text below as an answer and complete your nomination writeup:

> <a href="http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   <a href="http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   ###Notes:
>   This nominee would be a good choice because …

[image]

---

---

<sub>Дуже вільний переклад українською, читайте англійську версію для точної інформації. (Very free translation to Ukrainian, read the English version for precise info.)</sub>

В ідеалі модератори мають обиратися самою спільнотою, але спільнота ще не настільки велика за розміром, щоб можна було проводити власні вибори, тому ми призначимо трьох тимчасових модераторів для виконання модераторських обов'язків.

Ми потребуємо вашої підказки. Будь ласка, висувайте людей, яких би ви хотіли бачити тимчасовими модераторами. Ваш допис надасть нам цінну інформацію, завдяки якій ми зможемо зробити вибір. Ви можете почитати докладніше про цей процес тут: **[Модератори тимчасові](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).**

### Про процес номінування:

- **Номінуйте користувача**, додавши «відповідь» внизу. Кожна номінація має бути окремою відповіддю. Використовуйте шаблон наприкінці йього тексту, аби зробити номінацію.
- **Висування самого себе заохочується.** Це добровільна активність, тому користувачі не мають відчувати себе обтяженими, приймаючи таку посаду. Самовисування — це простий спосіб сказати: «Я дуже зацікавлений в цьому, тож хай мій допис говорить сам за себе.»
- **Розкажіть нам про кандидатів.** Номінації можуть містити посилання на іншу активність номінанта, наприклад: участь в Area 51, участь в інших сайтах чи будь-які релевантні думки/посилання, що нададуть нам інформацію для прийняття рішення.
- **Номінанти!** Будь ласка, відзначте згоду/незгоду з висуванням вашої кандидатури, відредагувавши відповідну відповідь. Також переконайтеся, будь ласка, що e-mail у Вашому профілі коректний, щоби ми могли зв'язатися з Вами. Факультативно Ви ще можете додати щось про себе після зазначення згоди (це заохочується).

  > Я приймаю/відхиляю цю номінацію.
  >
  > Вітаю, мене звуть / я живу / цікавинка про мене (все це необов'язково). Я живу в <місцевість>, тому я зазвичай активний на цьому сайті з <час доби> до <час доби>. Дещо інше, що ви, може, хотіли би знати про мене: …

### Ось чого ми чекаємо від кандидата в модератори:

Ми шукаємо учасників, які беруть активну участь у розвитку громади. Учасників, які:

- Були постійно активні протягом перших тижнів створення цього сайту.
- Демонструють зацікавленість у діяльності, спрямованої на створення спільноти на розділі meta свого сайту.
- Показують іншим приклад, демонструючи терпіння і повагу своїх колег по спільноті у всіх своїх дописах.
- Проявляють якості особистості, що описані у статті "Теорія Модерації" ([**A Theory of Moderation**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/))

---

### Шаблон для номінації

Для того, щоби номінувати кандидата, скопіюйте і вставте цей текст як нову відповідь, доповнивши її номером користувача і примітками:

> <a href="http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/**НомерКористувача**">
>   <img src="http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**НомерКористувача**.png"></a>
>   <a href="http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/**НомерКористувача**">
>   <img src="http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**НомерКористувача**.png"></a>
>   ###Примітки:
>   Цей номінант — хороший вибор, тому що …

[image]

Comment: What is the deadline for a nomination?

Comment: @Sasha Selections are typically made approximately 1 week after public beta starts... so about two weeks from now (barring any technical problems or concerns about going public).

Comment: If several participants nominate the same candidate — should their "answers" be merged into single "answer", or no (or it doesn't matter)?

Comment: @Sasha It's best to 'flag' the 2nd nomination for moderator attention. I can remove the duplicate nomination while notifying the author and inviting them to add their notes as comments to the original post. (I'll take care of this one, thanks).

Comment: Oh, I thought one post - one vote :) sorry for doubling

Comment: @RobertCartaino How to properly indicate that voting is over? Should this post be closed?

Comment: @Artemix the post was already marked status-completed, but I closed it  pointing to the pro tem announcement to further highlight that point.

Answer (score 18):

[image]

[image]
 [image]

#### In English:

I'm daring to nominate myself.

During the time of Private Beta, I became #1 user [by overall reputation](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), [total number of votes](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all), and [edits](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all). I'm #1 or #2 in four of five Review categories ([1](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats), [2](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/stats), [3](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/stats), [4](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats)). I'm also an [active Meta user](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8/bytebuster?tab=summary) (5Q and 8A so far).

**Being a Good Moderator**.

- I strongly believe in a **community-driven consensus** rather than enforcing the will of a few persons. The Moderator is only the last resort when everything else fails. However, I think that the Mods should lead by example, and this activity will require more time than a regular user would spend.
- I believe that most of the moderation tools are already available for every SE user (namely, voting, flags, reviews, and Meta).

**Being an Active User**.

- **I do believe in prooflinks**. Although not a *panacea*, searching on the Internet before asking helps write a better question, while doing this when answering helps avoid opinionated answers that only invite for refutation and open-ended discussion, reducing the overall quality of our posts. [Here's](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2552/2984) more details on this.
- Therefore, I'm an **active downvoter** (328 up, 75 down).
- This site has more new users who have never used StackExchange before. So, helping them participate this site and **write a better content** would help them becoming active on *other StackExchange sites*. So **a warmer welcome** is a key factor when reading first posts. The moderators should take the lead.

I am not a Moderator on other SE sites, so there would be no time conflict in this regard.

If elected, I hope I could bring my efforts to help Ukrainian Language.SE become a better place.

And good luck to all the nominees!

---

#### Солов'їною:

Візьму на себе сміливість самовисування.

Протягом участі у Private Beta я став користувачем #1 user [за загальною репутацією](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), [загальною кількістю голосів](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all) та [редагувань](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all). Наразі я #1 або #2 у чотирьох із п'яти Review categories ([1](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats), [2](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/stats), [3](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/stats), [4](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats)). Я також [беру активну участь у Meta](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8/bytebuster?tab=summary) (5 запитань та 8 відповідей).

**Бути Хорошим Модератором**.

- Я є великим прихильником **демократичного консенсусу** користувачів, на противагу до нав'язування волі кількох осіб. Модератор, у цьому світлі, виглядає як крайній засіб, коли усе інше не спрацьовує. З іншого боку, Модератори показують приклад власною поведінкою, і ця активність вимагає більших витрат часу, ніж це робив би «звичайний» користувач.
- Я щиро вірю у те, що більшість інструментів модерації вже доступні усім користувачам SE (а са́ме — голосування, флаги, reviews та участь у Meta).

**Бути Активним Користувачем**.

- **«Не вірю в силу слова я, а вірю тільки в силу пруфлінкі́в»**. Хоча посилання і не *панацея*, але користування пошуком в Інтернеті перед тим, як запитати, дає можливість сформулювати краще запитання, а при відповіді на запитання дозволяє уникнути безпідставних тверджень, які є лише запрошенням іншим користувачам починати спростовувати викладені тези. Зазвичай це виливається у пустопорожню дискусію виду «слово проти слова», що знижує загальну якість наших дописів. [Ось тут](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2552/2984) трошки філософії на цю тему (англ.)
- Враховуючи вищенаведене, я є **активним «мінусувальником»** (328 вгору, 75 униз).
- Цей сайт, напевне, має трохи більшу кількість нових користувачів, які допіру ніколи не користувалися StackExchange. Тому допомагати їм брати участь у сайті **і створювати якісний контент** дасть їм змогу ставати активними учасниками *інших сайтів сімейства StackExchange*. Тому **доброзичливе ставлення** ввижається мені ключовим фактором під час читання перших дописів новачків. Модератори мають брати на себе лідерство у цьому напрямку.

Я не є Модератором на інших сайтах SE, і у зв'язку з цим не матиму конфлікту з витратами часу.

Якщо буду обраним, сподіваюся, що зможу докласти своїх зусиль до того, аби зробити Ukrainian Language.SE цікавим і комфортним ресурсом.

І бажаю успіху усім іншим номінантам!

Comment: поки що ваша "програма" нічим не відрізняється від пустих обіцянок пересічного депутата: **де пруфлінки суперечок, які ви вирішили?** Це ж єдине в що ви вірите?

Comment: не варто хизуватися тим, що ви є **активним «мінусувальником»** - **це ніяк не свідчить про ваші розумові здібності**, а тим паче про прихильність до "демократичного консенсусу" . Для прикладу, я можу попросити свого трирічного племінника і він поб'є ваше "досягнення" за пів години.

Answer (score 17):

[image]

[image]

#### Примітки:

Цей номінант — хороший вибор, тому що

- Саме він створив [пропозицію Ukr.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94001/ukrainian-language)
- Був найактивнішим користувачем на етапі пробних запитань (5 питань, 8 коментарів до запитань з 71)
- Є найактивнішим на ме́ті (11 запитань, 22 відповіді)
- Щодо того чи іншого рішення намагається подавати порівняння плюсів і мінусів ([наприклад](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19/36))
- Жодного разу не був помічений як той, що диктує свою волю. Більше того, він завжди підкреслює, що рішення спільноти є завжди вирішальним.
- Він є активним користувачем на основному сайті (5 запитань, 20 відповідей, безліч коментарів)
- Його відповіді завжди дуже добре структуровані, а отже, він *має змогу* підтримувати такий само рівень якості на сайті взагалі

#### Notes

This nominee would be a good choice because:

- He is who actually wrote [proposal of Ukr.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94001/ukrainian-language)
- He was the most active on the stage of experimental questions (5 questions, 8 comments from a total of 71)
- He is the most active on meta (11 questions, 22 answers so far)
- He always tries to compare pros and cons of a possible decision ([for example](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19/36))
- I didn't spot him acting as a dictator in any meaning. Moreover, he always stresses that community decision is the most important thing.
- He is active on the main site (5 questions, 20 answers and **lots** of comments so far)
- His answers is always very well structured, that means he *can* maintain same quality level on the site overall

Sasha: Nash Bridges, thank you very much. But I suppose I will **decline** this nomination. I feel moderation to be not my type of activity (it may be exciting for me to do it a few times, but not regularly). When I saw this question for the first time, I thought something like “*I'll become the moderator only if there are no other candidates or all other candidates are weak, just to make the project not to fail*” — but I consider current candidates as good. “[Der Mohr hat seine Arbeit getan, der Mohr kann gehen](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%80_%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8E_%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%83,_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%80_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5_%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8)” looks not as insult for me, but as preferred way of living. And I don't go away fully, just prefer to participate in other ways. (Although I am still making a decision and theoretically may change my opinion before the deadline.) BTW, idea about pros and cons was [borrowed from bytebuster](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15/4).

Comment: @Sasha I've upvoted in case you change your mind :) I recommend using Ukrainian sources when possible: https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%80_%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8E_%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%83,_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%80_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5_%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, thanks. Sorry, not noticed that article in Ukwiki, fixed source :).

Comment: @Sasha Вибач, що набридаю. Це востаннє ) Розумію, що голосування не напряму впливає на вибір модераторів. Але за поточним голосуванням виходить, що замість тебе (якщо ти відмовишся) в модератори потраплю я. Я погоджуюся на це й зроблю що зможу, але ти явно більше часу приділяєш сайту все одно. У мене зараз трохи змінилася ситуація й часу поменшало, що можна, напевно, бачити з моєї активності на сайті. Прошу тебе ще раз подумати - можливо піти Мавром, коли будуть вибори модераторів, а на тимчасового модератора все ж таки погодитися... Ну і 16 користувачів за тебе проголосувало )

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, Ви не набридаєте :). Це в якісь мірі навіть приємно, якщо мене вважають гідною кандидатурою. Але я вже вирішив, що мені не варто. Те, що я багато часу приділяю сайту — це радше мій недолік; то є невміння розподіляти час між різними формами активності. Наприклад, якщо «нормальна» людина побачить, що їй не вистачає часу одночасно на роботу, дітей і сайт — які витрати часу вона скорочуватиме? — а я ні. Я й так іноді забагато часу сайту приділяю, а якщо я буду відчувати відповідальність — то тоді взагалі тут житиму. Тож краще я поки що побуду на лаві «запасних», на підхваті.

Comment: Так і психологічно комфортніше, і користі від мене, мені здається, більше буде. Щодо виборів постійних модераторів, то ще невідомо, коли вони будуть. Якщо в кінці публічної бети — то це аж через кілька років. Це звісно не означає, що Ви (чи хтось інший) зобов'язані «тягти лямку» до кінця; якщо хтось не може/не хоче, то, звісно, будемо змінюватися. Але я поки що не хочу «впрягатися». Тобто те, що Ви кажете, що не зможете приділяти багато часу — це в моїх очах є перевага — бо у Вас є такі поняття як «час», «достатньо/недостатньо часу» — в мене ні.

Comment: Я шизоїд-перфекціоніст. Я завжди хочу зробити все — і все ідеально. А виходить завжди якась @#$%^.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

[image]

#### Примітки:

Kyrylo Yatsenko буде гарним модератором:

1. *Тому що*, вочевидь, він має досвід у корисних колективних інтернет-активностях
2. *Тому що* він має солідний багаж знань із української мови і перекладу
3. *Тому що* він вніс своїми постами і відповідями значний вклад у стадію приватної бети

#### Notes

Kyrylo Yatsenko will be good at moderator role:

1. *Yes he can* because, apparently, he has experience with useful internet-community efforts
2. *Yes he can* because he knows a lot about Ukrainian Language and translation
3. *Yes he can* because he's already committed a lot to this private Beta with his questions and answers

---

Kyrylo Yatsenko: **I accept this nomination / Я приймаю цю номінацію.**

#### Cons:

- This is the first stackexchange site I actively take part in.
- I've switched to Ukrainian two years ago only.
- It is unpredictable how much time I'll have for this site (at some days 20 minutes only, on others several hours)

#### Pros:

- I have high hopes for this site.
- I sincerely believe in Be Nice policy.
- I spend most of free time for Ukrainian language. I have experience of switching to Ukrainian.

@Chizh, thank you for nomination - it is very pleasant.
@Sasha, thank you for making successful proposal of this site. I hope that you see support for you as moderator and will change your mind and agree to be moderator at least for some time.

---

#### Недоліки:

- Це перший сайт stackexchange, у якому я беру активну участь
- На українську перейшов лише два роки тому з російської
- Кількість часу для сайту непередбачувана (іноді є лише хвилин 20 на день, інколи декілька годин)

#### Переваги:

- Дуже вірю в цей сайт
- Свято вірю в be nice і поза цим сайтом :)
- Майже весь вільний час присвячую українській мові, добре знаюся на проблемах переходу на українську

@Chizh, дякую за номінацію. Дуже приємно.
Дякую @Sasha за започаткування успішної пропозиції цього сайту. Сподіваюся, через підтримку ти зміниш свою думку й погодишся бути модератором принаймні деякий час.

Comment: -1 тому що, ваш опис "ріже око"

Comment: @sage444 ласкаво просимо на ukrainian.SE тут ви можете зробити цей світ трішечки кращим. Наприклад, наразі ви можете більш детально описати які саме недоліки ви помітили у цьому дописі. Також вартопам'ятати про можливість редагування дописів - ви можете запропонувати свою, кращу версію допису, яка стане актуальною як тільки вона пройде peer-review

Comment: дякую, власне я розумію як працює SE і не редагув ваш пост тільки тому що це номінація на модератора і на мою думку це ваша справа підтримувати її в найкращому стані. Детально: мені здалось, що в першому пункті "активностей" в неправильному відмінку, а в третьому не подобається порядок слів

Comment: та й прикметників у вас забато, як на мене

Comment: @sage444 Дякую, ви праві принаймні щодо першого пункту. Хоча, мені здається, що це більше свідчить про те, що я недостатньо приділяю часу цьому ресурсові. Досі не зібрався оновити опис (ваші зауваження стосуються тексту, що його писав Chizh - мій текст лише після Kyrylo Yatsenko).

Comment: @sage444 дякую, виправив

Comment: @sage444, взагалі, мені здається не дуже правильним ставити мінус номінації через не найліпші формулювання. Бо, дивлячись на номінації, люди можуть підсвідомо сприймати їхню оцінку як оцінку **номінанта** спільнотою. А тут, якщо Ви помітили, автор номінації і номінант — **дві різні людини**. (Особливо, якщо уявити, що адміністрація SE може не завжди перекладати всі коментарі через Google Translate і глибоко вчитуватися в них, а просто «так, бачу „–1“, хмм…»).

Comment: @Sasha розумію вашу думку, але, робота модератора на мою думку це час і уважність. А тут маємо: номінуючий неуважно складає номінацію, номінований не приділяє ресурсу достатьньо часу щоб все поправити - чому я як користувач ресурсу маю підримувати таких кандидатів коли вони ще до отримання привілеїв не демонструють мінімальної відповідальності ?

Comment: @sage444, дякую за Вашу відповідь. Я розумію Вашу думку. Але незгоден з Вами.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

This nominee would be a good choice because:

- He was reasonably active in both Main Site and Meta from the very beginning.
- He looks like one of the most active on Meta for me. His activity seems to be quite constructive. He initiated several important discussions. He doesn't avoid to express his opinion in discussions. And his argumentation is usually quite reasonable.
- In general, he makes impression of patient and willing-to-understand. He *doesn't* have such traits as "oh, too long, I won't read this" and "just do it as I said, I'm right!!!". I.e. he tries to understand before criticizing and always argues his own position reasonably.
- He has [experience on the Russian SE](https://russian.stackexchange.com/users/551/artemix).
- Maybe my impression is biased, but when I read about moderator election, my first thought was: “Of course, [bytebuster](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/105/4) and Artemix. Hmmm, who else? Maybe [Kyrylo Yatsenko](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/111/4) or …?”. (Sorry, [Yellow Sky](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/110/4) and others — I really have nothing against you — just it was really my 1-st intuitive thought.) I was unsurprised that bytebuster was the first, but I am very surprised that nobody yet mentioned Artemix.

---

## I accept this nomination.

Thanks, Sasha, for this nomination!

As many of users we have on this site, I long waited for Ukrainian Language to be launched on StackExchange. I would like to make this place welcoming for all who want to learn the Ukrainian language.

I live in Kyiv, so I am generally active on this site from 10:00 AM to 11:00 PM. I'm not a professional linguist, but at some point in my life I understood that it is very interesting to me.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

[image]

#### Примітки:

Yellow Sky буде гарним модератором:

1. *Тому що*, вочевидь, він досвідченний стак ексчейнджер і розуміє як подібні ком'юніті працюють
2. *Тому що* він має кваліфікацію у багатьох мовах
3. *Тому що* він вніс своїми постами і відповідями значний вклад у стадію приватної бети

### Notes:

Yellow Sky will be good at moderator role:

1. *Yes he can* because, apparently, he is experienced Stack Exchange community member an knows mechanics of communities of a such kind
2. *Yes he can* because he is competent at several languages
3. *Yes he can* because he's already committed a lot to this private Beta with his questions and answers

Yellow Sky: I don't know if I could be a good moderator, I lack the feel of responsibility, but if I'm chosen *one of the moderators*, I'll do my best to fit the high Stack Exchange standards.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

This nominee would be a good choice because:

1. She knows the grammar very well and knows where to search for the information about Ukrainian language. Every time we have a conversation in comments, Oksana has a link or two to the peer-reviewed sources.
2. She respects the rules and sticks to the official Ukrainian grammar, so her choice will be of a reason, not of a wish.
3. She is an active member of a community with a wish to bring quality onto this part of the stackexchange.
4. Oksana listens to the opinions different form her own and changes her mind if someone provides her with the argumentation from the credible sources.

I'd say, pani Gubrenko is the only adult in this community... Just kidding.

Also, I see a lot of IT-workers on this site, but not quiet enough of professional linguists. I suppose, Oksana is a linguist with a degree, and we need her to make the moderation board more diverse.

**Oksana Gubrenko**

Dear @P.Vovk, dear all,

Many thanks for your appreciation and for being nominated!

I am so delighted!

It would be indeed a great honour, a great challenge and a great pleasure for me to be a community moderator, if I only had more time to devote myself to full extent.

Unfortunately, currently I combine two places of work with civil activity and therefore I am not constantly available to fulfil moderator's obligations.

Alternatively, I can offer being a back-up moderator if applicable under the requirements of the community.

Otherwise, I would be glad to continue to be an active user and will try my best to contribute to keep the community going.

Sorry to say, but for now **I decline the nomination**.

Nonetheless, I am sure the winners will be our best choice!

Wishing all the best to those who will be honoured and long live to the community!

Comment: She didn't respond. Does she know about this topic? Does she know about the Meta site at all (i.e. she is new at SE)? Maybe we should post her a link to this answer (e.g. replying 1 of her comments [here](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/435/oksana-gubrenko?tab=activity)).

Comment: @Sasha I thought mentioning p. Oksana in the post would make it appear in her notifications. I see you've already posted a comment, let's wait and see what happens next)

Comment: I know only about @-mentions in comments and chat (and it works only for those users that have already written something in that comment thread / in that chat room at least once). AFAIK, mentioning a user in a post (question/answer) doesn't generate a notification (reasoning is smth like: "it's not a forum, questions/answers are for everybody"; though for some cases in Meta it would be useful; [1](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/97471/252301)).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

#### Примітки:

1. Ініціативний
2. Відповідальний
3. Вимогливий

Попри те що я люблю і цікавлюсь солов'їною у мене немає достатьно часу для цієї відповідальної і корисної справи. Тому я відхиляю цю номінацію. Але я в будь якому випадку постараюсь бути активним учасником спільноти.

#### In english:

Beside my love to Ukrainian language I have no enough time for moderation. So I decline my nomination. But in any case I will contribute to this community

Comment: Дякую, це справді приємно, але мушу зізнатись що мого запалу навряд чи вистачить на довго тому не впевнений що ця номінація гарний задум

Comment: @Chizh, жарт​⁠​⁠?

Comment: @sage444 якщо **уважно** прочитати пост, то там можна побачити наступну строку *"Номінанти! Будь ласка, відзначте згоду/незгоду з висуванням вашої кандидатури, відредагувавши відповідну відповідь."*

Comment: @Sasha Ukrainian.SE - SE можливостей!

Comment: @Chizh та я б із задоволенням, але в мене немає пермішенів редагувати відповіді ))

Comment: @sage444 ок, зробив ком'юніті вікі. привілеїв має вистачити для редагування

Comment: @Chizh дякую, поедітав