# Чи не занадто ми суворі до новачків?

Tags: discussion, quality-content

Неодноразово бачив, як хтось новий приходить на цей сайт, намагається писати питання/відповідь (буває, частково доречну) — отримує безліч мінусів і «гнівних» (з його точки зору) коментарів і більше не повертається.

Приклади: [22](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/22/4), [30](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/30/4), [144](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/144/4), [166](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/166/4), [332](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/332/4), [426](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/426/4), [504](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/504/4), [509](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/509/4), [610](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/610/4), [622](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/622/4) + [623](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/623/4) (написав відразу 2 відповіді), [734](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/734/4), [736](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/736/4), [742](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/742/4), [743](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/743/4), [808](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/808/4) + [809](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/809/4) (написав відразу 2 відповіді).

Я не кажу, що в усіх цих випадках мінуси/коментарі безпідставні. Що я хотів сказати, що, можливо, те, які стандарти ми вимагали в себе під час приватної бети (і, мабуть, вимагатимемо далі — як у «вже навчених» користувачів), і те, що ми маємо вимагати в новачків — дві різні речі. Що їм треба давати якусь «фору» і не вимагати відразу «100%-ї якості».

Крім того, мені здається, що я занадто жорстко висловився, а інші занадто буквально сприйняли «[аргументуйте вашу відповідь](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/4)». Можливо, слід було  висловитися «щоб зробити вашу відповідь кращою, намагайтеся її аргументувати». Бо не завжди можна об'єктивно аргументувати, є безліч цікавих питань, де немає достатньої інформації (або користувач не в силах її знайти). В англійській версії ([1](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659/252301), [2](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)) насправді немає нічого про пруфи (в інших топіках — радше про недопустимість *питань*, що притягують opinion-based-відповіді, а не самих *відповідей*). Це було радше індивідуальне бачення (на основі трішки Вікіпедії, [трішки rus.SE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTTJx.png)).

Адже мета сайту — в першу чергу збір широкої спільноти, а не власне самовираження. Хоча й власне самовираження теж, без більшої спільноти ми просто не зможемо (ентузіазм малого колективу рано чи пізно скінчиться).

Власне, я не впевнений щодо жодного з цих пунктів, я лише хочу обговорити:

- зменшити вимогу до об'єктивності аргументації;
- поблажливість до новачків.

Що я конкретно пропоную:

- Послабити «аргументуйте вашу відповідь» (і наше ставлення до цього).
- Не мінусити відразу новачків. Лише лагідно коментити. (Але мінусити старичків.)
- Намагатися відповідати новачку індивідуально, даючи конкретні поради щодо конкретної ситуації. А не загальний шаблон типу «ваша відповідь не відповідає критеріям, тому що <пара незрозумілих для нього слів>»). Тим більше — не англійською (якщо допис українською). Адже кожен новачок на вагу золота, і варто виділити трішки часу, щоби пояснили *саме йому*, в чому проблема.
- Не кидати відразу декілька коментарів одному новачку. (Я маю на увазі, критикуючих коментарів.) Це створює враження, що «всі на нього накинулися». Якщо «критикуючий» коментар вже є — інший кидати лише в крайньому разі. (Можливо, домовитися з автором першого коментаря в чаті, щоби він його прибрав — якщо вважаєте його невдалим.) (Це, звісно, не стосується похвальних коментарів, питальних коментарів і коментарів до неновачків.)

Обговорімо це (я не впевнений). Можливо, я перегинаю палицю в інший бік.

<sub>P.S.: Перепрошую, що затягую речі, які обіцяв зробити, але не зробив.</sub>

Comment: `Це було радше індивідуальне бачення (на основі трішки Вікіпедії, трішки rus.SE)` - StackExchange це не Вікіпедія, і переймати тут їх правила з вимогою посилань на авторитетні джерела, нмсд, не надто правильно.

Comment: Плюс, є https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer і там стандартний текст, в якому написано "Links to external resources are encouraged" (а не *required*), "Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful", "Brevity is *acceptable*, but fuller explanations are better". Новачок, що прочитає ці рекомендації, буде неприємно здивований, коли його перша відповідь нахапає мінусів та негативних коментарів, через відсутність посилань на авторитетні джерела.

Answer (score 10):

Згоден з тим, що потрібно більше "няньчитись" з новими користувачами. Далеко не всі взмозі абстрагуватись і не сприймати чиїсь зауваження/мінуси до питання чи відповіді як щось особисте.

Моє бачення наступне: впевнений, якість альтернативних відповідей (а новачки, як правило, горять бажанням допомагати) буде набагато вища і такі відповіді все одно наберуть більше "плюсиків". Людина, повертаючись до питання, на яке відповіла, побачить, що інші відповіді матимуть більше голосів і це, як на мене, буде найкращим уроком, як формувати свою відповідь наступного разу.

Я не думаю, що це призведе до *значного* падіння якості контенту. У мене склалось враження, що ядро користувачів стабільно активне і триматиме планку на високому рівні.

Словом, підтримую пропозиції про послаблення та індивідуальний підхід.

Comment: На жаль, мушу поставити -1. Протягом 2.5 років після того, як цей допис написано, його автор [зробив](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/584/maccstax?tab=topactivity) рівно **0 posts edited, 0 helpful flags**, чим допоміг приблизно нулю новачків. З чого можна зробити висновок, що аргументація автора ні на чому не ґрунтувалася.

Comment: @maccstax Розумна думка! Душе шкода бачити, що портал втратив прихильника такої позиції. І тим паче шкода, якщо це сталося через токсичну спільноту.

Comment: @bytebuster висловлюючи свою думку автор не обіцяв особисто займатися порталом. Навіть якщо він пішов від нас, думка не втратить своєї слушності ні через 2.5, ні через 5, ні через 100 років. Ставлячи -1 ви приховуєте корисні дописи від спільноти. Якби можна було, я б поставив downvote на ваш коментар.

Comment: @belkka, вітаю вас у мережі Stack Exchange і на цьому сайті. Ця мережа **значно** відрізняється від форумів, чат-бодів і подібних сайтів. Головна відмінність — **тут нема такого явища, як «думка автора»**. Авжеж, насправді самі автори не позбуваються своїх суб'єктивних думок щодо будь-якого явища, але інформація, викладена у запитаннях і відповідях, має відповідати певним [критеріям якості](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/8). Якщо завгодно — критеріям *вікіпедичності*. […]

Comment: […] Користувачі або погоджуються з такою політикою, або не погоджуються і йдуть на форуми і групи у соцмережах, де корисний (підтверджений поважними джерелами) контент тоне у морі «особистих думок» і «я, нікому не відомий юзер анонімус77, вважаю так». Дописи, що не відповідають критеріям, або редагуються, або видаляються. Користувач, який слідує принципу «давайте няньчитися з новачками, але нехай цим займається хтось, а не я», заслуговує на «мінус» у даному випадку.

Comment: Я згоден з belkka — з розміру внеску maccstax не варто робити висновок про логічність (чи нелогічність) його аргументації.

Answer (score 3):

Оскільки всюди бачу мої downvotes¹, висловлюся. :)

> Що їм треба давати якусь «фору» і не вимагати відразу «100%-ї якості».

І так, і не так.

> [**Stack Exchange is about posts, not users.**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130054/187133) […] If you think something is wrong, comment (and downvote if you are confident enough).

> [Usually on SE](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2887/2984) we like to judge content, and not the poster of this content. One of the implications of this is that **we are as hard on content from new users as we are on content from old users**.

Ми судимо дописи, а не користувачів.

Як наслідок — поганий допис від новачка повинен отримувати такий само відгук, як поганий допис старого користувача.

На цю тему було багато дискусій на Meta.SE, включно з такими радикальними пропозиціями, як [**приховувати авторство допису**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198/187133) (протягом деякого часу після публікації або за інших умов) — саме для того, щоб **унеможливити суддівство за авторством**.

Допомагати новачкам — це важлива справа. Ми маємо цьому приділяти увагу. Хоча-б унаслідок того, що *новачків — експоненційно більше*, ніж досвідчених користувачів.

Але варто усвідомлювати, що *анонімних відвідувачів — у свою чергу, експоненційно більше*, ніж зареєстрованих. Вони приходять з ґуґлопошуку², читають відповідь, яку шукали, і йдуть геть. А вже з десятого (умовно) разу вони зацікавлюються нашим сайтом, реєструються, починають дописувати тощо.

Або **не** зацікавлюються. Якщо сторінка нашого сайту, на яку їх привів Ґуґл, містить погані запитання/відповіді **унаслідок того**, що ми *«послабили вимоги до аргументації відповідей»*.

І тому **єдина річ, якою ми «не торгуємо» — це якість дописів**.

Я дуже радий, що [політика](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/105/8) доброзичливого привітання новачків [набуває популярності](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/124/8). Але ми не можемо робити за новачка усе.

---

> Бо не завжди можна об'єктивно аргументувати, є безліч цікавих питань, де немає достатньої інформації (або користувач не в силах її знайти).

Дійсно. Існує багато цікавих запитань, на які не існує об'єктивної відповіді. Вони можуть викликати фурор у якомусь чаті. Вони можуть отримати 1,000 коментарів, 10,000 лайків і 2,000 перепостів у соцмережах.
**Але — вони не вписуються у формат StackExchange.**

Нам повезло: ми — не Politics.SE. :-) Тому у нас нема у чистому вигляді протистояння між правими-лівими чи лібералами-консерваторами. Але і у нас кожен має свою *думку* з того чи іншого приводу. Неаргументована думка — завжди суб'єктивна. А суб'єктивний допис якраз запрошує прихильників «іншої» думки до спростування. Такого ж суб'єктивного, як сам допис.

І саме цього ми намагаємося уникнути.

Must read: [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

---

> Не мінусити відразу новачків. Лише лагідно коментити. (Але мінусити старичків.)

`-1…-2`, як на мене, — нормальна реакція на допис новачка. [Ненормальна — це -9](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/10934/2984).

Окрім того, ми повертаємося до тези, що судити треба допис, а не автора.

---

- ¹) окрім незрозумілого посилання «504»
- ²) так має бути, це ознака healthy Beta

Comment: «Stack Exchange is about posts, not users.» — так, це вірно. Але **пости не беруться самі нізвідки, їх пишуть користувачі**. А щоби вони їх писали, вони мають відчувати себе як вдома. І для цього, **можливо**, варто не вивалювати на них увесь свій шквал критики від самого початку, а якось «дозувати» її.

Comment: 504 — підведіть мишку, так у `title` написано (невдала ідея була запхати той текст туди).

Comment: > _Ми судимо дописи, а не користувачів_
На жаль, деякі користувачі судять скоріше користувачів. Наприклад, у цьому [коментарі](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133/Чи-не-занадто-ми-суворі-до-новачків#comment940_135) автор зізнається, що поставив -1 НЕ через зміст допису, а через дії користувача за межами допису. Думка висловлена у дописі ані критикується, ні спростовується, ні доповнюється. Тобто такі люди ставлять -1 навіть якщо думка **слушна** і корисна для спільноти (через якісь переконання щодо висловившої її людини). Тим самим відлякуюсь цікавих користувачів.