# "We're looking for long answers". Do we?

Tags: discussion, quality-content

In [the question «Як українською „Само собой разумеется“?»](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1281/4):

- Per my opinion, every answer (as of 2017-04-26 06:47 AM UTC) is OK, because:
  (1) They provide laconic and complete answer.
  (2) They provide reference.
- But (supposedly) [bytebuster](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/8/bytebuster) put the following banner near **almost every** answer:

  > We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Don't you consider the banners to be unreasonable?

---

<sub>Per my opinion, we need **[good](//meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)** answers, not long answers. Short answers are **often** bad, but not always. It makes sense to put this banner only on answers that are short-and-bad, but not on short-but-good. (If not [rephrase](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/268422/252301) it at all.)</sub>

<sub>Per my opinion, "Just say *X*" is (most always) a bad answer; but "[The *A* dictionary/book/linguist](//example.com/link-to-proof) suggests to say *X*" is often ok.</sub>

Comment: -1: This does not look like a genuine question. As the 2nd part of the post shows, you already know the answer. Also, this post needs editing out the  invitations for opinionated answers like "do you consider?"

Comment: Будь ласка, відредагуйте запитання, щоб воно було запитанням, а не оголошенням. Інакше на нього буде неможливо відповісти об'єктивно, і його треба буде закрити.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the question itself is poorly asked and as such provokes short answers which are in fact correct. It's like asking "Is January the last month of the year?" with answers like "No, the last one is December".

The question is too simple to give long answers. So I don't think that the banners help here, because they are fighting with effects and not with the cause.

Comment: Exactly. As I said in comments to my answer, I'm a bit reluctant to close/delete bad posts single-handedly, especially if others push it as high as upto +8 votes. OTOH, we need helping the users see the difference between the good and bad posts.

Comment: Personally I don't consider the question as "**very** bad". While the question is certainly shorter and less-detailed than it should be — such oversimple questions (providing a possibility to give obvious but concrete answer) can attract new answerers. Like "WOW! know it!! I can answer it!!!"

Comment: I.e. I'd criticize that question primarily for being too-short/not-enough-detailed, but not because too-simple. Though it's my personal opinion, I may be wrong.

Comment: And in such case, IMHO, it's really important to differentiate laconic-but-complete answers from not-simply-short-but-really-useless answers.

Answer (score 0):

As per several similar questions here on Meta, our primary goal is providing with quality content.

One-line answers can be only useful in very rare cases. **In most situations, they are not.** Poorly researched answers may be quite good at BBS's, forums, or amateur discussion boards or publics on social media.
But they are not good for a StackExchange quality standards.

Imagine, a hyperlink in one of the answers is desperately pointing to a dictionary's page for "С" letter as a "proof" *(yeah, it could be only worse if they linked a home page of the site:)*. And someone even attempts to claim that this link is good.

Think of it: non-backed claims and poorly-researched answers are very easy to deny — **also with** non-backed arguments, poorly-researched thoughts, or, most often, simply with users' opinions.

This site is about the established facts, references, and well-researched claims, not about opinions or emotions. Period.

Admittedly, **the question itself is bad**. It fails to provide with neither a context, nor even an attempt for self-answering. I tempted to close it on the first time, but then decided to wait for someone close-voted it first.
**Anyway, a bad question is not an excuse for bad answers.**

P.S. The *post notices* are standard as they apply the entire StackExchange network.

---

Links:

- [Чи не занадто ми суворі до новачків?](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133/)

Comment: "In most situations, they are not." — yep, exactly as I've said in the question. But **in rare cases when they are** — **we shouldn't attack/downvote them**, huh?

Comment: "Poorly researched answers…" — sure. But, please, don't switch topic from short to poorly-researched answers. They're not the same thing (an answer can be laconic and still complete).

Comment: **And what about all other answers you put the banner too**?

Comment: @Sasha, we do not attack anyone. Everyone here has their right to vote on any post, according to their understanding. Re "all other answers?" — what is the question?

Comment: I am not about attacking somebody. I'm about attacking an answer: (IMHO undeservedly) downvoting it, (IMHO undeservedly) putting a banner. I am about all other answers to the same question, where somebody put banner too.

Comment: @Sasha, you're right, notices are a poor compromise. On mature SE sites, where a solid core of active users arises, bad answers get downvoted to oblivion, receive deletion-flags, and subsequently get removed. Notices are intended to remind about the quality standards; they are not for marking bad posts that deserve deletion. Mea culpa.

Comment: So, you say: you put these banners not to say "they are bad", but just to remind "short answers are **usually** not good (though this one may be fully ok)" — am I right? (Did I understand you correctly?)

Comment: @Sasha, have you read what the post notice says?

Comment: Sorry, what "post notice"?

Comment: @Sasha, please, the post notices is what you call "attacking the answer". These yellow thingies.

Comment: OK, I've read the "yellow thingie". Then I'm still waiting for an answer for <<So, you say: you put these banners [onto answers in Main] not to say "they [the answers] are bad", but just to remind "short answers are usually not good (though this one may be fully ok [!])" — am I right? (Did I understand you correctly?)>> Logical emphasis at "[!]" is important.