# Additional Moderators Needed

Tags: discussion, moderation

Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until this site reaches a critical mass to hold an election, I need to appoint another provisional Moderators to help moderate this site.

**We recently had 2 moderators step down from this site. As discussed in [this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/208518), just about the only criterion remaining to keep a site open is having enough users (three minimum) willing to step up to moderate it.**

### WE NEED YOUR HELP!

Please nominate some folks you might like to see become the provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide some valuable support to help us make our selection. You can read more about the process here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

## The Nomination Process:

- Nominate a user by adding an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity. I added a short template (below) to help you with that process.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- Nominations can include links to other activities: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **The nominee should indicate their acceptance** by editing the answer (not commenting) to say they accept. Optionally, nominees are encouraged to write a bit about themselves following the nomination. You can use the `---` markup to separate the nominee's commentary from the original nomination. See the example below.

## Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are seeking out members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active in the site's activities;
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities;
- Leads by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write;
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Here is an example nomination entry. You can copy-and-paste from the format below:

> ```
> <h2>[username](<main profile link>) </h2>
>
> <h2>[Meta Profile](<meta profile link>) </h2>
>
> Notes:
>
> <why you feel nominee would be a useful addition to the pro tem choices>
>
> ---
> ```
>
> <sup><sup>(this section is edited in by the nominee)</sup></sup>
>
> ```
> I accept/decline this nomination
>
> I am name/age/location/fun fact/all optional. I live in location, so I am 
> generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may 
> want to know about me are…
>
> etc.
> ```

Answer (score 6):

[image]

[image]

#### Примітки:

Цей номінант — хороший вибор, тому що

- Він створив [пропозицію Ukr.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94001/ukrainian-language)
- Був найактивнішим користувачем на етапі пробних запитань (5 питань, 8 коментарів до запитань з 71)
- Є активним на ме́ті (23 запитань, 39 відповідей)
- Він завжди підкреслює, що рішення спільноти є завжди вирішальним.
- Він - активний користувач на основному сайті (19 запитань, 260 відповідей)
- Я вважаю що він зможе втілювати принцип "вести своїм прикладом" на нашому сайті.

P.S.: Я знаю що у минулому Sasha відхиляв пропозицію стати модератором, але можливо він вже змінив свою думку.

#### Notes

This nominee would be a good choice because:

- He is who actually wrote [proposal of Ukr.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94001/ukrainian-language)
- He was the most active on the stage of experimental questions (5 questions, 8 comments from a total of 71)
- He is active on meta (23 questions, 39 answers so far)
- He always stresses that community decision is the most important thing.
- He is active on the main site (19 questions, 260 answers)
- I think he can implement the "Lead by example" principle.

P.S.: I know that in previous moderator nominations Sasha declined the proposal, but I hope that he has changed his mind since that time.

---

I agree.

Comment: This time I accepted such proposal in personal mailing even before this announcement on Meta was created. So, the problem is actually to choose the 2nd (and the 3rd?) moderator. But thanks for your attention.

Comment: @Sasha AFAIK we are looking for 2 new moderators. If you have accepted the proposal than just one additional is required.

Comment: We're looking for 2, indeed. But Sasha had already previously agreed to be one of those 2. It felt weird to say we were looking just for the missing one, and then for the community to see 2 going out and 2 coming in — so I just did this instead, and told Sasha they could leave their nomination here as a formality :)

Comment: -1: this user has repeatedly shown their leaning to keep bad, low-quality posts instead of improving it. A major number of this user's Meta posts have been dedicated to re-stating their point about low-quality posts: https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/213/ https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/215/ https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/191/ https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/194/ and I have a strong impression that this user will be able to enforce this policy if appointed a Moderator.

Comment: Also, this user's reviews to "Low Quality Posts" has been [**almost ultimately** "Looks OK"](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/history?userId=4), "Close Votes" reviews are [almost always "Leave Open"](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/review/close/history?userId=4). In addition, they have **virtually zero post flags** (strictly speaking, 10 attempted, 5 helpful). This is not a Mod-grade amount of flags.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

[image]

I hereby nominate myself.

#### Примітки:

Цей номінант — хороший вибір, тому що:

1. Йому важлива якість запитань на цьому сайті (він постійно просить нових користувачів у той чи інший спосіб поліпшити запитання або відповідь).
2. Він один з найактивніших користувачів цього сайту як на основному його розділі (5-те місце по репутації), так і на меті.
3. Він вже частково приділяє увагу модераторським активностям на кшталт оцінки постів нових користувачів або закоротких постів.

#### Notes

This nominee would be a good choice because:

1. The quality of posts on this website is very important for him (he's one of those users who always ask new users to fix sth in or add sth to their questions and answers).
2. He's one of the most active users both on the main ukrainian.stackexchange.com (5th) and on meta.
3. He pays attention to moderation activities even without being a moderator.

P.S.: Another thing I would like to stress here is that I can become an active moderator only after the 6th of August. If the community, as well as other moderators, is OK with it and with my self-nomination in general, I will be glad to take this position pro tempore.

---

I agree.

Comment: I sent you an email inviting you to moderate over a month ago, on June 5th — maybe it ended up in your spam folder?

Comment: @JNat I had absolutely no time back then. I am still very busy. That's why "P.S." and 6th of August.

Comment: Ah, gotcha — mind replying to the email now, then, just for the record/as a formatility? :)

Comment: @JNat done it. Anything else?

Comment: I'll reply to it with further info/instructions